# How to disable Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC application with jQuery.

I have already tried so many things like:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.disable.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
$('input').disableAutocomplete();
$('input[type="password"],input[type="text"],form').disableAutocomplete();
$("input:text,form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
$("form")[0].reset();
<form id="edit-profile-form-desktop" autocomplete="off">
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.FirstName, new { @placeholder = "first name ", @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "test", autocompletetype = "disabled" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.LastName, new { @placeholder = "last name ", @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", autocompletetype = "disabled" })
```

After trying all these options, I'm still getting prefilled textboxes in my add/edit page and biggest problem is I'm getting inappropriate/previous data for edit page.

What would do I here to disable autocomplete by jQuery/HTML or backend programming?

I'm mainly facing this in mobile phones.

Comment: have you checked if its due to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            $("input[type='text']").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");
            });
        }
        catch (e)
        { }
    });
```

It will disabled autocomplete from your all input types.

Thanks

Comment: Will this workout???

$("input[type='text'],input[type='password'],form").each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");
                });

Comment: Yes ! I have applied this in my own project

Comment: ohh! you have include password, sorry I did not saw that.. I think it would work..

Comment: Yes Ishan it is working, I have tried this.. Please let me know if not working on your side

Answer (score 0):

For me worked

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName,
                new Dictionary<string, object> {
                    { "class", "form-control autocomplete" },                       
                    { "ng-maxLength", "512" },
                    { "autocomplete", "off"},
                })
```